# Heroku Spring Boot start

Tags: java, spring-boot, heroku

I tried to run my Spring Boot Application on Heroku. The application starts correctly, but after that it crashes instantly with following error:

```
2019-03-19T11:45:28.343758+00:00 app[web.1]: 2019-03-19 11:45:28.343  INFO 4 --- [           main] main.Application                         : Started Application in 23.503 seconds (JVM running for 24.505)
2019-03-19T11:46:24.818535+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H20 desc="App boot timeout" method=GET path="/api/ping/" host=fill-it.herokuapp.com request_id=b6fea897-b436-4918-bc6f-3cde7e4f94aa fwd="5.184.28.91" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-03-19T11:46:32.330719+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2019-03-19T11:46:32.173577+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 90 seconds of launch
2019-03-19T11:46:32.173731+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2019-03-19T11:46:32.312711+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2019-03-19T11:46:32.734743+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=fill-it.herokuapp.com request_id=5802be29-5937-4d0f-93fb-7a01b4972d9e fwd="5.184.28.91" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-03-19T11:46:33.049778+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/api/ping/" host=fill-it.herokuapp.com request_id=4c7eff04-ce3a-4a63-b7bf-312b44658e40 fwd="5.184.28.91" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Anyone got similar problem?

Comment: Do you have a `Procfile` or are you relying on a deafult command? You probably need to add `-Dserver.port=$PORT` somewhere.

Comment: I had Procfile but without this property. Now works like a charm. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your `Procfile` has `-Dserver.port=$PORT` in the java command.

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed it by adding `server.port=${PORT:5000}` in `src/main/resources/application.properties`.

Source: [sample Spring Boot app from Heroku's doc](https://github.com/heroku/java-getting-started/blob/main/src/main/resources/application.properties)