# Spring boot app deployed on Heroku crashes on start with H10 status

Tags: spring-boot, heroku

I succesfully deployed my spring boot app on heroku with github, but it crashes on start with code H10, this is the logs:

```
2021-09-19T06:27:33.505475+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=clinica-uni.herokuapp.com request_id=c9fa6842-53fc-4d3e-95d4-c2d32975e678 fwd="79.27.232.54" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-09-19T06:27:33.799165+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=clinica-uni.herokuapp.com request_id=01d741e2-a3a2-4a30-b591-347bffb4629f fwd="79.27.232.54" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-09-19T06:55:29.642840+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-09-19T06:55:32.161587+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command "java -Dserver.port=40251 $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/clinica-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"
2021-09-19T06:55:33.079687+00:00 app[web.1]: Create a Procfile to customize the command used to run this process: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile
2021-09-19T06:55:33.107663+00:00 app[web.1]: Setting JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS defaults based on dyno size. Custom settings will override them.
2021-09-19T06:55:33.111587+00:00 app[web.1]: Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xmx300m -Xss512k -XX:CICompilerCount=2 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 
2021-09-19T06:55:33.182378+00:00 app[web.1]: no main manifest attribute, in target/clinica-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
2021-09-19T06:55:33.308030+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-09-19T06:55:33.447778+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

This is application.properties:

```
#==================================
# = Thymeleaf configurations
#==================================
spring.thymeleaf.check-template-location=true
spring.thymeleaf.prefix=classpath:/templates/
spring.thymeleaf.suffix=.html
spring.thymeleaf.servlet.content-type=text/html
spring.thymeleaf.cache=false
spring.thymeleaf.encoding=UTF-8
server.servlet.context-path=/
#
#==================================
# = Logging configuration
#==================================
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=debug
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql=trace
logging.level.org.springframework.web=DEBUG
logging.level.it.uniroma3.siw.spring=DEBUG
#
#==================================
# = Datasource configuration
#==================================
spring.jpa.database=POSTGRESQL
spring.sql.init.platform=postgres
spring.datasource.type=com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
spring.datasource.hikari.connectionTimeout=30000
spring.datasource.hikari.idleTimeout=600000
spring.datasource.hikari.maxLifetime=1800000
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost/clinica
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true
#
#==================================
# = Webserver configuration
#==================================
server.port= 8080
server.error.whitelabel.enabled=false 
server.error.include-stacktrace=always
#
#==================================
# = Misc configuration
#==================================
spring.messages.basename=messages/message
#
#==================================
# = Security configuration
#==================================
spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SecurityAutoConfiguration
```

And this is pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>clinica</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>clinica</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies> 

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Hinally, if it helps, I changed build tag from this:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

into the current one because it didnt't deploy at all on heroku, but I don't know what it actually does, I just found it here on stackoverflow.

Anyone knows how to solve the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55240402/heroku-spring-boot-start) should help you.

Comment: I've seen something like that but I can't find the Procfile